# How to include the spaces?

Tags: c, arrays, file

I am trying to write a program that takes the words from a file, and puts those in a dynamic array. However when I try to run my code the program copies it all except for the spaces. How do I fix this?

> This is a test does it work?

But I get the following:

> Thisisatestdoesitwork?

```
char** getWords(char* filename, int* pn){
char** tmp = (char**)malloc( 1000*sizeof(char));
int *temp=(int*)malloc(1000*sizeof(int);
int c;
int counter = 0;



FILE* fileInput = fopen(filename, "r");
if(fileInput == NULL){
    return tmp; // return if file open fails
}


while((c=fgetc(fileInput)) != EOF){
    result = fscanf(fileInput, "%c", &c); //try to read a character
    if(isalpha(c)){ //chararect alphabetical
    tmp[counter] = c; // safe int to array
    counter ++;
    printf("%c", c); fflush(stdout);
    }
    else{ // if read not succesfull
        fscanf(fileInput, ""); // needs to scan anything not a character
    }
    if(counter > 100){ // to not exceed the array
        break;
    }
    if(feof(fileInput)){ // to check if at the end of the file
        break;
    }

}
fclose(fileInput); // closing file
*pn = counter;
return tmp;}
```

My main Function:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
int n;
char** a = getWords("opdracht_4_5.c", &n);
if (a != NULL){
    puts("gevonden woorden:");
    for (int i = 0;i < n; i++){
        printf("%3d %s\n",i,a[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0;i < n; i++){
        free(a);
    }
    free(a);
}
return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

}

Comment: this is a perfect opportunity to learn debugging. are you on Linux? then compile your program with `-g` and run `gdb --args ./mytool` and enter `r`.

Comment: A nice debugging primer can be found here: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: There are many mistakes in this code.

Comment: For starters: `char s[100];` is not initialised before being used for the 1st time.

Comment: I have initialised char s and removed some the **

Comment: I still have problems with the Strcat and the malloc. it gives errors, there which I have no clue of how to fix them.

Comment: Does the code compile without warnings?

Comment: I have added them now, sorry I forgot to do so.

Comment: `c` never changes inside the loop.  It is usually written `while ((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)`  And you are using `strcat` with the uninitialized array `temp`.  That's a problem.

Comment: In your function for what purpose you use *pn? However, try to search for some example of sorting strings.

Comment: Unless you are using `realloc`, there's no point in using `malloc` for an array this small and you cannot really call it "dynamically allocated".

Comment: There are so many mistakes in your code.... Most of the come from your teacher not really imparting the essense of how / why functions should be created, and how to break a problem down into logical steps.  I will try to give you a guide...

Comment: I am currently redoing the code to a similar thing I have on my pc regarding doing this but with integers, Hopefully this works better.

Comment: I am writing an answer for you, I would like you to read that before you make your next attempt :-) however this will take about 15-20 minutes to answer

Comment: For that I am extremely gratefull, I also wrote some new code which I think could work, only there is one thing I am missing. Which I do not know how to write correctly. If you could also take a look at that and maybe tell me what I did wrong and why afterwards. This would help me a lot more as well, ty ;-)

Comment: Great, show what you are doing, I'll comment on that as well.

Comment: I have updated my code to what I think could be correct.

Comment: You do *not* want to use scanf.  Interleaving reads with fgetc and scanf is a disaster that's already happened.

Comment: Contacted my teacher, he told me that I had to use a fucntion known as isalnum

Comment: Why is your array of type `char *`?  That is an array of char, which is suitable to hold a single word.  If you want an array of words, you many want to consider using an array of `char *`.  In other words, you want `char **words`.

Comment: Only problem i am currently engaging is that It doesn't take the whitespace and 1st charecter The just don't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will read the file, put each word in an array

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char** getWords(char* filename, int* pn){
    char input[100]; // array to hold each word
    char** tmp; // double pointer
    int counter = 0;
    int words = 0;
    int c;

    tmp = malloc( (*pn)*sizeof(char*)); // allocate pointers for number of words
    if ( tmp == NULL) {
        printf ( "malloc failed\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    FILE* fileInput = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(fileInput == NULL){
        printf ( "file open failed\n");
        *pn = 0; // no words entered
        return tmp; // return if file open fails
    }

    while(( c = fgetc(fileInput)) != EOF){
        if( isalnum(c)){ // is alpha or number
            input[counter] = c; // save to array
            input[counter + 1] = '\0'; // save a \0 to the end to make a string
            counter ++;
        }
        else{ // not alpha or number
            if ( counter > 0) { // if there are characters, save the word
                tmp[words] = malloc ( strlen ( input) + 1); // memory for this word
                strcpy ( tmp[words], input); // copy the word to the array
                words++;
                counter = 0;
                if ( words >= *pn) { // got all the words wanted
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(counter > 98){ // too many characters for input, start a new word
            tmp[words] = malloc ( strlen ( input) + 1);
            strcpy ( tmp[words], input);
            words++;
            counter = 0;
            if ( words >= *pn) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fileInput); // closing file
    *pn = words; // save number of words
    return tmp;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int n;
    int i;

    printf ( "enter the number of words to obtain\n");
    scanf ( "%d", &n);
    char** a = getWords("opdracht_4_5.c", &n);
    if (a != NULL){
        puts("gevonden woorden:");
        for ( i = 0;i < n; i++){
            printf("%3d %s\n",i,a[i]);
        }
        for ( i = 0;i < n; i++){
            free(a[i]); // free each word
        }
        free(a); // free the pointer to the words
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The input file I used had these as the first two lines
`#include<stdio.h>`
`#include<string.h>`

I get this output:

enter the number of words to obtain
6
gevonden woorden:
  0 include
  1 stdio
  2 h
  3 include
  4 string
  5 h

Comment: For some reason it keeps saying that the isalnum is implicit decleration of function

Comment: it didn't work it still prints all the words one after another. without the spaces that are inbetween.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few problems with your code. Here's a start:

- You don't test the return value of `fopen()`.
- You don't test the return value of `malloc()`.
- You assign the return value of `fgetc()` to a variable of type `char`. Plain `char` is compatible with either `signed char` or `unsigned char`. In order to make a distinction between a character and `EOF` (which is negative), the `fgetc()` function returns a character converted to **`unsigned char`** (or EOF). You need to test for `EOF` **and then** convert the value to a plain `char`.
- The `is...()` function expects an `int` argument whose value is in the range of an **`unsigned char`** or `EOF`. If you have a plain `char`, you first have to cast it to `unsigned char`, or you can pass the return value of `fgetc()` straight to `isalpha()`.
- You attempt to append an zero-length `char` array (`temp`) to an uninitialized `char` array (`s`), and you do not test if there is enough room in the target array. This is broken for more reasons than than I care to enumerate.
- You allocate memory for an array of 1000 pointers to `char`, but you never allocate memory for the `char` pointers themselves.
- You try to append your buffer (`s`) to an uninitialized pointer (`*tmp`).
- You call `strlen()` on something that is not null-terminated.
- You never return the length of the array.
- You call a number of functions that have not been declared.

Answer (score 0):

> ### This answer is as yet incomplete
>
> Please allow me to finish this before commenting on it  -- Thank you

---

There are a lot if issues with your code, I won't clean it up for you. However I would like to give you some hints on how your program SHOULD be coded:

Your main objective is to read a file and load the content word by word in an array.

Sorting is an incorrect use because that implies you want to sort them alphabetically or in some other order after loading it into an array.

Okay, so first things first, let's figure out the overall operation of our program. We'll call our program kitten, because it's not quite as powerful as cat.

To run our program we will assume that we give it the filename we want to read on the command-line as follows:

```
$ ./kitten somefile.txt
```

and expect the output to be:

```
word1
word2
word3
.
.
.
wordN

Total words: N
```

So, let's get started, first we make sure that our user specifies a filename:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int usage(const char *progname);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        usage(argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int usage(const char *progname)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage is:\n\t%s filename\n", progname);        
}
```

Now that we know that our program can get a filename, let's try to open the text file, if there is an issue with it we use perror to display the error and exit the program, otherwise we are ready to use the file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int usage(const char *progname);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    FILE *fp;

    if (argc < 2) {
        usage(argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!fp) {
          perror(argv[1]); /* display system error, with the filename */
          return -1;
    }

    /* TODO: file manipulation goes here */

    fclose(fp); /* close the file */
    return 0;
}

int usage(const char *progname)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage is:\n\t%s filename\n", progname);        
}
```

Now in C each function should perform just one task.  The task should make human sense. For example if the function is supposed to read words into an array, then that's all it should do, it should not open a file or close a file, which is WHY the code above does not create a function for opening the file the way you did. Your function should take in `FILE *` as the file to read.

Because we use the `FILE *` as input we'll start the function name with an `f` to keep with the stdio convention. Ideally, the function should take a pointer to `char *` (strings) to store the words in.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int usage(const char *progname);
size_t fload(FILE *fp, char **wordlist_p);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    FILE *fp;

    if (argc < 2) {
        usage(argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!fp) {
          perror(argv[1]); /* display system error, with the filename */
          return -1;
    }

    if(fload(fp, wordlist_p) < 0) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Something went wrong\n")
    }        

    fclose(fp); /* close the file */
    return 0;
}

int usage(const char *progname)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage is:\n\t%s filename\n", progname);        
}

size_t fload(FILE *fp, char **wordlist_p)
{
       size_t rv = -1; /* return value */
       return rv;
}
```

Now we run into a conceptual problem.  How do we allocate memory for `wordlist_p`? I mean we don't have any idea about how big the file is, we also don't know how big the biggest word in the file is.

### Crude approach

Let's first try an think about it the simple way:

```
     Point to the beginning of the `wordlist_p` with a `tail_pointer`
     Read the file line by line, (we assume no hyphenation)
     For each line split the line up along white spaces, 
        Allocate space for the number of words in the `wordlist_p` array
        For each word in the split line
           Allocate space for the word itself 
           Save the pointer to the word at the tail_pointer
           Advance wordlist_p tail_pointer
        Next word
     Next Line
```

Let's look at what the `fload` function would look like with these steps above,

### More to come ##

Comment: Please refrain from posting incomplete answers. [This is considered a bad practice.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)